# How to recurse through a list of tuples?

Tags: haskell, recursion, tuples

I am attempting to make a *very* simple program that finds the average distance a group of points is from 0. The input will be a group of tuples (i.e. (1,2) and (2,3)), it should calculate each points distance from 0 and then find the average.

I understand the logic and the general formula (again, it's *very* simple), which I have here:

```
averageDist ((x,y):xs) = (sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)))/length xs
```

I just don't understand the syntax for lists when using tuples. As you can see, I tried (x,y):xs and while it compiles, ghci thinks that all values are different types. How can I fix this program so I can iterate and apply the formula to each tuple?

I'm totally new to Haskell and I appreciate any and all help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write an average function:

```
average :: [Double] -> Double
average xs = ...
```

and a distance function:

```
distance :: (Double,Double) -> Double
distance (x,y) = ...
```

Then you can use these functions together with `map`:

```
averageDistance :: [(Double,Double)] -> Double
averageDistance xs = average ( map distance xs )
```

Comment: Is there a way to use list comprehension instead of multiple functions?

Comment: This is exactly to what I'm looking for. I changed it a little, but I'm still getting big errors related to type issues? Any idea on what could be causing it?

Comment: @raine `sum [sqrt(x*x + y*y) | (x,y) <- xs] / length xs` perhaps.

Comment: @groovy That will work if you change `length xs` to `fromIntegral (length xs)`, `length` returns an `Int` and `/` requires a `Fractional`.

Comment: @raine glad you got a handle on it.

Comment: I want to add two things - 1) if you have a long list you should combine the adding and length step as the list is only garbage collected after the calculation of length, 2) use the `sqrt` part only if you really need it - if you just compare the distances, you might as well compare the squares of the distances, which is giving the same result with less work.